# CSS: how to position element in lower right?

Tags: css

I am trying to position the text element "Bet 5 days ago" in the lower right-hand corner.  How can I accomplish this?  And, more importantly, please explain so I can conquer CSS!

[image]

Comment: Would be easier if you would show us your HTML and CSS that you currently have.

Comment: On conquering CSS, I'd highly recommend the following book http://books.google.ie/books/about/CSS_The_Definitive_Guide.html?id=rdtCRLXAL78C&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Lets say your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <p class="bet_time">Bet 5 days ago</p>
</div>
```

Then, with CSS, you can make that text appear in the bottom right like so:

```
.box {
    position:relative;
}
.bet_time {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

The way this works is that absolutely positioned elements are always positioned with respect to the first relatively positioned parent element, or the window. Because we set the box's position to relative, `.bet_time` positions its right edge to the right edge of `.box` and its bottom edge to the bottom edge of `.box`

Comment: But how to solve it if `.box` itself has to be `position:absolute` ? Impossible?

Comment: Your `.box` is still `position:relative`.

Comment: `.box2` is `position:absolute`

Comment: You might need to set the parent to be `display:inline-block;`

Comment: container must be relative, and the content therein must be absolute for positioning , brilliant ! thanks

Comment: OP's question is a little vague, but this solution positions it to the bottom right corner of the screen, not the page.

Comment: No, this solution positions it in the bottom right of the parent container, regardless of page/viewport size. If your equivalent of `.box` is set to 100% width/height, that's very likely the viewport size, not the page.

Answer (score 35):

Set the CSS `position: relative;` on the box. This causes all absolute positions of objects inside to be relative to the corners of that box. Then set the following CSS on the "Bet 5 days ago" line:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

If you need to space the text farther away from the edge, you could change `0` to `2px` or similar.