# How to change the reference point of an html element?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an iframe that has a dynamic size and needs to stay in the bottom right of the screen. There are multiple elements in play such as window size and and a min-width, but ALL of my problems would be solved if I could reference my iframe from the bottom right rather than the bottom left.

So, is there a way to treat the iframe in a way that I could say something like:

```
iframe {
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

in css and have it stuck in the bottom right corner, even when the size of the frame changes?

Comment: On a side note, you should almost never need iframes any more.

Comment: You could put the Iframe in a div and try the solution suggested here:<br><br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956043/css-how-to-position-element-in-lower-right

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
iframe {  
    position:fixed; 
     bottom:0;  
     right:0;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the `position` of your `iframe` to `fixed`:

```
iframe{
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply `position:fixed` to the iframe and have stuck to the bottom right hand corner like so:

```
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/baav59vh/